# Nancy: Serving static content (e.g. index.html) from "/"?

Tags: c#, nancy

I'm trying to make a single page web application using Nancy. Therefore, I want my root URL to serve a plain .html file, without any view logic or whatsoever.

I tried

```
Get["/"] = parameters => Response.AsHtml("content/index.html")
```

But there's no `AsHtml`.

I tried a custom bootstrapper with

```
conventions.StaticContentsConventions.Add(
    StaticContentConventionBuilder.AddFile("/", @"content/index.html")
);
```

But apparently it thinks that "/" is not a file - Nancy gives me a directory listing on `http://localhost:<port>/` instead.

What do I do? This shouldn't be this hard, right?

ps. Any way to turn that directory listing off? It feels insecure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put it your views folder and do:

```
Get["/"] = _ => View["index"];
```

The directory listing is nothing to do with Nancy, whatever hosting you're using is displaying that.

Comment: Thanks. I'll put this as the accepted answer, even though it feels rather unsatisfactory. I've ended up simply putting an nginx in front to serve my static files, leaving Nancy only for backend things.

Comment: What about debugging, how do get the index.html file when debugging with visual studio?

Comment: this is not hosting a static file.

Comment: @Steven Robbins : sorry, I like Nancy, but this is not the "super-duper-happy path". See e.g. HotTowel.Angular Nuget package, completely clientside stuff, server agnostic. Doesn't run with NancyFx, because Nancy doesn't support it, not even through the "intended" way of StaticContentConventionBuilder. It gives a security exception, even though I only allow html files, which is perfectly save. No way to override without putting half an hour into this. I f I wanted that, I could have stayed with WebApi. This is NOT superduperhappy, this is FAIL. Sorry.

Comment: jst make StaticContentConventionBuilder.AddFile("/", "/index.html") work.. really, it's a basic usecase. Or better, automap that stuff for any html, js, css via a simple method on StaticContentConventionBuilder, for any file. I'm right now really puzzled why the user doesn't come first here.

Comment: I agree that this is not "super-duper-happy-path"!

Answer (score 21):

Add a module that serves `index.html` by default:

```
public IndexModule() : base("")
{
    Get[@"/"] = parameters =>
    {
        return Response.AsFile("Content/index.html", "text/html");
    };
}
```

Then serve the rest of your files using a convention in your bootstrapper:

```
protected override void ConfigureConventions(NancyConventions nancyConventions)
{
    nancyConventions.StaticContentsConventions.Add(StaticContentConventionBuilder.AddDirectory("/", "Content"));
    base.ConfigureConventions(nancyConventions);
}
```

Comment: Not sure where "Response.AsFile" comes from, but `GenericFileResponse("Content/index.html", "text/html")` does the trick.

Comment: Just adding expression `Get[@"/"] ... ` to existing Module worked for me.