# Nancy static-file handler not part of application pipeline?

Tags: c#, owin, nancy

I'm trying to log every request made to Nancy in the application pipeline, but for some reason I cannot seem to log the static file requests. Neither of the following captures the request for static files.

```
ApplicationPipelines.BeforeRequest += ((ctx) => {
    LogTo.Info($"{ctx.Request.UserHostAddress} - {ctx.Request.Method} {ctx.Request.Path}");
    return null;
});

ApplicationPipelines.AfterRequest += ((ctx) => {
    LogTo.Info($"{ctx.Request.UserHostAddress} - {ctx.Request.Method} {ctx.Request.Path} - {ctx.Response.StatusCode}");
});
```

Anything that isn't a static file is logged perfectly fine.

Also, I'm using the convention located here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21477824/1657476. Nancy is Self-Hosted using Nowin and is the only component added to the owin app builder.

Is the static file hander not part of the Nancy application pipeline? If so, How can I hook into the static file requests?

[Documentation](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Managing-static-content) says it should be (part of the pipeline). So I don't understand why I can't pick it up. I've even tried directly inserting the pipeline hook at the beginning too with `AddItemToStartOfPipeline`

Answer (score 1):

The static file handler is **no longer part of the Nancy pipeline**. Documentation was out of date. See Issue: https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/issues/2328

If you use Nancy with Owin you can use middleware to capture the request and response (equivalent to `AfterRequest`):

```
app.Use(new Func<AppFunc, AppFunc>(next => (async context =>
{
    var sendingHeaders = (Action<Action<object>, object>) context["server.OnSendingHeaders"];

    sendingHeaders(state =>
    {
        var ip = context["server.RemoteIpAddress"];
        var port = context["server.RemotePort"];
        var method = context["owin.RequestMethod"];
        var path = context["owin.RequestPath"];
        var status = context["owin.ResponseStatusCode"];

        LogTo.Info($"{ip}:{port} - {method} {path} - {status}");

    }, context);

    await next.Invoke(context);
})));
```

You need the `OnSendingHeaders` hook because Nancy does not pass through if it handles the request.